# Skype4com auto accept contact request

Tags: vbscript, skype, skype4com

I'm using a VBScript to auto accept Skype incoming contact request:

```
Public Sub Skype_UserAuthorizationRequestReceived(ByVal pUser)
    pUser.IsAuthorized = true 
End Sub
```

This works but is there a way to prevent Skype from alerting me through the tray?

[image: tray icon]

I have already removed notification for contact request:

[image: configuration]

but it still appears.

It's also giving me a strange error:

> Skype4COM.Skype.1:  Invalid value given to ISAUTHORIZED/ISBLOCKED (code: 80020009)

I tried another approach of using

```
oSkype.Client.OpenAuthorizationDialog(pUser.Handle)
```

but it's giving an 'OPEN User already authorized' error.

Answer (score 1):

I got an example that might help you.

```
    Private Sub FRAccept(pUser As User)
    If FlatToggle1.Checked = True And pUser.IsAuthorized = False Then
        pUser.IsAuthorized = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The 'pUser.IsAuthorized = False' fixed the 'OPEN User already authorized'.

FlatToggle1 part gave an error 'Object required: 'FlatToggle1''. Is there something else i have to do before this? I don't know much about VBS.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I'm pretty sure if you delete the 'FlatToggle1.Checked = True And' part it will fix the problem